# AngularJS How do you parse JSON into multiple divs?

Tags: json, angularjs

I am trying to learn AngularJS and went through the Codeacademy and Code School courses, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to load JSON data into multiple divs.

There is a fiddle of what I'm trying to do here:
http://jsfiddle.net/oqk7tukL/1/

So in my controller code I have some 'JSON' data, which is how I am going to be storing JSON that I pass to my app. What I need to be able to do is have a list of all the projects show up in a div, and have all of the modules for each project as a list in a separate div. Right now my code is not loading anything at all, and I'm not sure what is wrong with it.

**JS**

```
function DataController($scope) {

  $scope.project = [
      {
          name: 'Trello',
          desc: 'Project management app.',
          modules: [
              {
                name: 'Trello1',
                desc: '1st Trello'
              },
              {
                name: 'Trello2',
                desc: '2nd Trello'
              }            
          ]
      },
      {
          name: 'Straw Poll',
          desc: 'Poll creation app.',
          modules: [
              {
                name: 'Straw Poll1',
                desc: '1st Straw Poll'
              },
              {
                name: 'Straw Poll2',
                desc: '2nd Straw Poll'
              }            
          ]
      }    
  ];

};
```

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app>

    <div ng-controller="DataController as dcon">

       <div>
          <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="proj in project">{{proj.name}}</li>  
          </ul>
      </div>

      <div>
          <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="mod in proj.module">{{mod.name}}</li>
          </ul>
      </div>

   </div>

</div>
```

I found an example of data posting in a fiddle on another site and it had the JS laid out similar to what I have without using var app, etc. Is this current practice, or was the example using bad practice?

Comment: You reference `modules` in your controller, but reference `module` in your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some change:

**JS**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['angular.filter']);
myApp.controller('DataController', ['$scope', function($scope){


    $scope.project = [
        {
            name: 'Trello',
            desc: 'Project management app.',
            modules: [
                {
                    name: 'Trello1',
                    desc: '1st Trello'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Trello2',
                    desc: '2nd Trello'
                }            
            ]
        },
        {
            name: 'Straw Poll',
            desc: 'Poll creation app.',
            modules: [
                {
                    name: 'Straw Poll1',
                    desc: '1st Straw Poll'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Straw Poll2',
                    desc: '2nd Straw Poll'
                }            
            ]
        }    
    ];
}]);
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">

    <div ng-controller="DataController">

        <div>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="proj in project">{{proj.name}}</li>  
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="mod in project | map: 'modules' | flatten">{{mod.name}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Link demo: https://jsfiddle.net/y4jh0ux7/

Comment: I see how you changed it, and it almost works, but the modules still don't show up when I view the fiddle.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. I've never seen the map option anywhere? Do you have a link to documentation for it?

Comment: Bunch of useful filters for AngularJS (with no external dependencies!): https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter